# $.mobile.changePage no funciona para iOS en app cordova

Tags: jquery, ios, phonegap

Tengo un código en la página de inicio de una app para iOS, desarrollada con phonegap/cordova, que después de unas comprobaciones de valores en el localstorage, ejecuta la carga de otra página html con el código

**$.mobile.changePage("./configuracion.html?_1="+ (new Date()).getMilliseconds());**

En la apk para android que genero funciona sin problema, pero para la versión iOS, se queda en la primera página y no redirecciona, no ejecuta el changePage.
Tampoco devuelve error, y los console.log que ponga, los imprime correctamente, incluso uno que sitúe después de esa línea.

Ese mismo código en apps con versiones antiguas de iOS estuvo funcionando bien.

**Log de simulador iOS:**

```js
2021-03-12 10:07:53.000939+0100 Cuidem EV[3199:112299] Apache Cordova native platform version 6.2.0 is starting.
2021-03-12 10:07:53.001056+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] Multi-tasking -Device: YES, App: YES
2021-03-12 10:07:53.009285+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] Could not load the "LaunchStoryboard" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.xxx.xxx"  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.136729+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] The preference key "AllowNewWindows" is not defined and will default to "FALSE"  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.137554+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] The preference key "MediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay" is not defined and will default to "TRUE"  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.141743+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] The preference key "AllowBackForwardNavigationGestures" is not defined and will default to "FALSE"  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.141827+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] The preference key "Allow3DTouchLinkPreview" is not defined and will default to "TRUE"  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.141907+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] CDVWebViewEngine will reload WKWebView if required on resume 
2021-03-12 10:07:53.141976+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] Using WKWebView  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.142455+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] [CDVTimer][console] 0.202060ms  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.142606+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.050068ms  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.143358+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] Unlimited access to network resources  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.143516+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 0.795007ms  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.143638+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.028014ms  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.144098+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] [CDVTimer][inappbrowser] 0.380993ms  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.144170+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 1.983047ms 
2021-03-12 10:07:53.213807+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process Cuidem EV  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.213911+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.213991+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.367485+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] IAB.close() called but it was already closed. 
2021-03-12 10:07:53.641744+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] BuildInfo packageName    : "com.xxx.xxx"  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.641849+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] BuildInfo basePackageName: "com.xxx.xxx"  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.641907+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] BuildInfo displayName    : "xxxEV"  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.641978+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] BuildInfo name           : "xxxEV"  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.642053+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] BuildInfo version        : "1.0"  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.642121+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] BuildInfo versionCode    : "1.0"  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.642183+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] BuildInfo debug          : YES  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.642245+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] BuildInfo buildType      : ""  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.642309+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] BuildInfo flavor    : ""  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.654126+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] chequeoinicial 2  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.654305+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] A2  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.654432+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] A3  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.654565+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] lenguaje es  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.654671+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] A10  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.654777+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] A11  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.654905+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] b  
2021-03-12 10:07:53.655046+0100 xxxEV[3199:112299] A13-1
```

**cordova plugin ls**

```js
cordova-plugin-buildinfo 1.1.0 "BuildInfo"
cordova-plugin-camera 5.0.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.2 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.1.0 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 5.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.2 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 6.0.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-vibration 3.1.1 "Vibration"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 3.6.2 "Diagnostic"
```

**Installed platforms:**
android 9.0.0
ios 6.2.0

**xCODE**
Version 12.4 (12D4e)

¿Qué puede ocasinar que no ejecute el cambio de página?

Answer (score 0):

He solucionado este problema añadiendo en el config.xml las siguientes líneas:

> ```
> <preference name="scheme" value="app" />
> <preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
> ```

Según la web oficial de cordova, desde el 20 de abril es necesario incluirlo.